# Ultimate Cron installation Table 'db_name.ultimate_cron_log' doesn't exist

Tags: installation, cron

After installing the ultimate cron module version 8.x-2.0-alpha4,
When I navigate to (/admin/config/system/cron/jobs), I get the following error meassage -

**Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.ultimate_cron_log' doesn't exist: SELECT l.* FROM {ultimate_cron_log}** l WHERE (l.name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (l.log_type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) ORDER BY l.start_time DESC, l.end_time DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => system_cron [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 0 ) in Drupal\ultimate_cron\Entity\CronJob->loadLatestLogEntry() (line 526 of modules\ultimate_cron\src\Entity\CronJob.php).
Drupal\Core\Database\Statement->execute(Array, Array) (Line: 640)

I have tried uninstalling and installing it again, but the error persists.
Kindly help.

Comment: has the module installed properly ? If not uninstall an reinstall it . And also did you run drush updb after installing the module ?

Comment: Have you checked the issue queue? Alpha modules are wont to break...

Comment: @Clive I tried to install the same alpha module in a fresh drupal install and it's working there, ans Table 'ultimate_cron_log'' is getting successfully created, may be there is some conflict occuring due to which module is not able to create the Table. But I am not able to debug that.

Comment: @miststudent2011, I already tried uninstall and reinstall, even unistall was giving error through UI, so I have to manuallly delete module from sql and delete the folder. I am not using drush, install/ uninstal through GUI.

Comment: @Clive Also this module is available in alpha and dev mode only for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following to fix the issue.  Manually create tables.

```
CREATE TABLE 'ultimate_cron_log' (
  `lid` varchar(176) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Lock ID',
  `name` varchar(166) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `log_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Log type',
  `start_time` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Timestamp of execution start',
  `end_time` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Timestamp of execution end',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User ID',
  `init_message` text COMMENT 'Initial message',
  `message` text COMMENT 'Message',
  `severity` int(11) DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT 'Max severity level of the execution',
  PRIMARY KEY (`lid`),
  KEY `idx_last` (`name`(80),`start_time`,`end_time`,`log_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Logs';
CREATE TABLE 'ultimate_cron_lock' (
  `lid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Lock ID',
  `name` varchar(166) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `current` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Current lock',
  `expire` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Expiration time of lock',
  PRIMARY KEY (`lid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`name`,`current`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Locks';
CREATE TABLE 'ultimate_cron_signal' (
  `job_name` varchar(166) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of job',
  `signal_name` varchar(166) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of signal',
  `claimed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is signal claimed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_name`,`signal_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Signals';
```